# UINavigationcontroller at the bottom of UIViewcontroller to hold multiple views

Tags: iphone

In the appDelegate.m i have created `navigationController` `initWithRootviewcontroller` so that when my application launches `UIViewController` loads with `navigationController` and i want to display this `navigationBar` of the `navigationController` at the bottom of the `UIViewController`. But with this code it is showing at the top eventhough defined the frame.

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

UIViewController *myViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 435, 320,25)];

_window.rootViewController = navigationController;

[_window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Anyone knows how to show navigationcontroller at the bottom of the `UIViewController`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Apple will not like your app based on the fact it's very confusing to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `UINavigationController` and from the `navigationBar` property:

> navigationBar The navigation bar managed by the navigation controller.
>   (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) UINavigationBar *navigationBar
>   Discussion **It is permissible to modify the barStyle or translucent
>   properties of the navigation bar but you must never change its frame,
>   bounds, or alpha values directly.** To show or hide the navigation bar,
>   you should always do so through the navigation controller by changing
>   its navigationBarHidden property or calling the
>   setNavigationBarHidden:animated: method.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)